# Need help understanding a paragraph pertaining to friend declaration

Tags: c++, friend

However, you can define a function in a friend declaration. **The class must be a non-local class, function, the function name must be unqualified, and the function has namespace scope.** The following example demonstrates this:

```
class A { void g(); };

void z() {
class B { // friend void f() { }; }; 
} 

class C { // friend void A::g() { } 
friend void h() { } 
};
```

Though I understood what's meant by `The class must be a non-local class` but after that comma it eludes me or that function word alone surround by comma is  typo?. What exactly whole para means word for word I mean. Thanks

P.S Above para is stolen from ibm C++ reference -> https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzarg/cplr042.htm

Comment: Looks like a typo to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the wording from C++14 standard:

> **[class.friend]/6** A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class (9.8), the function name is unqualified, and the function has namespace scope. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> class M {
>   friend void f() { } // definition of global f, a friend of M,
>                       // not the definition of a member function
> };
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

Comment: **the function has namespace scope** please explain that with example, I mean friend function definition inside class having namespace scope means what? . Thanks

Comment: It's not a condition, it's a description of the outcome: "and the function [that results from this definition] has namespace scope [as opposed to being a member of the class]" I'll add the complete paragraph to the quote - there's an example, and the example has a comment which makes this clear.

Comment: So defining a friend function inside a member class is not valid? Thanks

Comment: No, [it's fine](http://rextester.com/KOT71195). The function is still a namespace scope function though, not a member of the enclosing class.

Comment: Some confusion with my prior experiments. Somehow, the link has code of one program, but the output of another. [This works](http://rextester.com/GUCO70843)

Comment: I do agree the wording is pretty awkward. It remains unchanged from C++98 onward; I suspect it's simply that no one bothered to look at it closely.